# data table DT[i, j, by] does not select groups using criteria in i, trying to filter on number of unique values within group

Tags: r, select, filter, data.table, unique

I am not sure whats going on here with my data, maybe I am missing something simple.

My dataset has an id 'dSc' and a cluster (point) assigned to each id. I want to filter out those ids which have only have a single cluster assigned to them,

e.g. `BS:100021 has only 1 cluster point assigned to it` whereas `BS:100135 has 6 cluster point assigned to it` from the following example:

```
set.seed(1) 
xx  <- cbind(rep("BS:100021",30),rep(1,30))
yy  <- cbind(rep("BS:100135",60),rep(1:6,10))
mm  <- as.data.table(rbind(xx,yy))
names(mm) <- c("dSc","Cluster")
```

But if I want to filter out `"BS:100021"` n similar and I am trying

```
mm[length(unique(Cluster)) > 1,.SD,dSc]
```

I am still getting

```
          dSc Cluster
 1: BS:100021       1
 2: BS:100021       1
 3: BS:100021       1
 4: BS:100021       1
 5: BS:100021       1
 6: BS:100021       1
 7: BS:100021       1
 8: BS:100021       1
 9: BS:100021       1
10: BS:100021       1
11: BS:100021       1
12: BS:100021       1
13: BS:100021       1
14: BS:100021       1
15: BS:100021       1
16: BS:100021       1
17: BS:100021       1
18: BS:100021       1
19: BS:100021       1
20: BS:100021       1
21: BS:100021       1
22: BS:100021       1
23: BS:100021       1
24: BS:100021       1
25: BS:100021       1
26: BS:100021       1
27: BS:100021       1
28: BS:100021       1
29: BS:100021       1
30: BS:100021       1
31: BS:100135       1
32: BS:100135       2
33: BS:100135       3
34: BS:100135       4
35: BS:100135       5
36: BS:100135       6
37: BS:100135       1
38: BS:100135       2
39: BS:100135       3
40: BS:100135       4
41: BS:100135       5
42: BS:100135       6
43: BS:100135       1
44: BS:100135       2
45: BS:100135       3
46: BS:100135       4
47: BS:100135       5
48: BS:100135       6
49: BS:100135       1
50: BS:100135       2
51: BS:100135       3
52: BS:100135       4
53: BS:100135       5
54: BS:100135       6
55: BS:100135       1
56: BS:100135       2
57: BS:100135       3
58: BS:100135       4
59: BS:100135       5
60: BS:100135       6
61: BS:100135       1
62: BS:100135       2
63: BS:100135       3
64: BS:100135       4
65: BS:100135       5
66: BS:100135       6
67: BS:100135       1
68: BS:100135       2
69: BS:100135       3
70: BS:100135       4
71: BS:100135       5
72: BS:100135       6
73: BS:100135       1
74: BS:100135       2
75: BS:100135       3
76: BS:100135       4
77: BS:100135       5
78: BS:100135       6
79: BS:100135       1
80: BS:100135       2
81: BS:100135       3
82: BS:100135       4
83: BS:100135       5
84: BS:100135       6
85: BS:100135       1
86: BS:100135       2
87: BS:100135       3
88: BS:100135       4
89: BS:100135       5
90: BS:100135       6
          dSc Cluster
```

Comment: Try `mm[, if (uniqueN(Cluster) > 1L) .SD, by=dSc]`. This is the current idiom for the operation you're after. `uniqueN` does the same thing as `length(unique())` here.

Comment: This would be a much better question if you could edit the title to describe the problem even a little bit.

Comment: @Gregor I understand ,but was at loss of word while putting up the question .

Comment: @Frank it works , is there a reason `mm[length(unique(Cluster)) > 1,.SD,dSc]` does not work

Comment: @Bg1850 Yes. `DT[i, j, by]` applies the filtering operation in `i` before looking at `j` or `by`. The syntax might be extended to allow for filtering *after* looking at `by`, too, but it is not available yet. One proposed extension is here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788 I linked to your question there so the package authors see it and can post an answer if/when the extension is made.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the explanation , I as an user would assume if its like sql then filtering operation should come after `j` or `by` ,its more intuitive as well for me atleast .

Comment: It does map to SQL, but `i` is for "WHERE" and there is no "HAVING" (yet). See the bottom of the fourth slide here: http://user2014.stat.ucla.edu/files/tutorial_Matt.pdf More tutorials for the package are here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started and you can also click "Presentations" or "Articles" along the sidebar.

Comment: @Gregor, Bg1850: I tried to improve the question title and statement

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
list.of.dSc <- NULL

for(i in seq_along(unique(mm$dSc))){
    if(length(unique(mm[mm$dSc == as.character(unique(mm$dSc)[i]), "Cluster"])) == 1){
        list.of.dSc <- c(list.of.dSc, unique(as.character(mm$dSc))[i])
       }
}

mm[!(mm$dSc %in% list.of.dSc),]

         dSc Cluster
31 BS:100135       1
32 BS:100135       2
33 BS:100135       3
34 BS:100135       4
35 BS:100135       5
...
```

You find all instances (or, each dSc) where there is only one cluster class, add them to a list (`list.of.dSc`), and then use `%in%` to filter `mm` for all entries that are *not* in that list.

It's not very pretty, but I think it solves your question.

Comment: No ,not really. i want to filter out `dSc` for which there is only one cluster

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding your question. Would you just select the column you want to see? Meaning:

`mm[as.numeric(mm$Cluster) > 1, "dSc"]`

Comment: Please see Frank's comment,thats exactly what I want to achieve

Comment: @Bg1850 I've amended my code. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Or `test = with(mm, tapply(Cluster, dSc, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1L)); mm[ mm$dSc %in% names(test)[test], ]`

Comment: @AustinTaylor  I was more interested in knowing why filtering does not work . Although this does solve the problem here ,I would rather avoid using a loop in a data table which have million row .